# Please display editor and poster flairs side by side on smaller screens

Tags: feature-request, design, responsive-design

This is the normal situation:

> [image: user flairs side by side]

This is the situation on screens 965px or less:

> [image: user flairs above one another]

However, we still have a large gap where these could fit, and it pushes the content down.

I would prefer it if the flair appeared below the post menu options, so they could take up the full width for longer:

> [image: user flairs side by side with post menu above]

And it allows the screen to shrink as small as 850px:

> [image: narrow screen with flairs side by side and post menu above]

Comment: Also, this is another inconsistency: on mobile page the editer is under the author, but in your screenshots they're swapped.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ and on the app the editor and poster are next to each other, but editor on the left, not right. It’s woefully inconsistent.